# Compare values from different rows and column to get single result

Tags: mysql

Here  is description of my scenario:

**myTable**:

```
ID name width1 width2 parameter1 parameter2 code
1  AAA  0      10     500        750        10001
2  AAA  0      10     750        1250       10002 
3  AAA  0      10     900        1400       10003
4  AAA  0      10     1150       1650       10004
.................................................
.................................................
.................................................
```

Lets say that I'm working with some "subjects" that have their own properties. Based on subject properties and some calculations with that same properties I should take "**code**" from this table.

So, this one subject that I'm currently working with has name: **AAA**, width: **5**, and with my calculations i get parameter: **1000**. After I have all of necessary attributes I can compare them with rows in myTable. For bigger picture I'll select all from this table but my goal is to get code. Here is query for that:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name="AAA" AND 5>=width1 AND 5<=width2 AND 1000>=parameter1 AND 1000<=parameter2
```

After this I get these two rows:

```
ID name width1 width2 parameter1 parameter2 code
2  AAA  0      10     750        1250       10002 
3  AAA  0      10     900        1400       10003
```

Just to mention, here could be one row. But, if I get two rows I need to do following. My whole concentration is on these parameters in a way that I'm comparing spread between my parameter and parameter2 in first row and spread between my parameter and parameter1 in second row.

```
parameter -> parameter2
1250 - 1000 = 250
&
parameter1 -> parameter
1000 - 900 = 100
```

So, if spread1:250 > spread2:100 take code2:00002 else take code3:00003.

My question is, how to compare values from different rows and columns? As you can see I have two rows and values from different column. What I need is a way to select these specific values for comparison.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear - Your Select did not deliver the promoted results -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b946/2/0

Comment: dude, not clear, really? I made little mistake and fixed it! try now.:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be solved by Greatest from Least, so at first we get the least value and order this descent.

```
SELECT 
  code
FROM 
  myTable 
WHERE 
  name="AAA" 
AND 
  5 >= width1 
AND 
  5 <= width2 
AND 
  1000 >= parameter1 
AND 
  1000 <= parameter2
ORDER BY 
  Least( parameter2-1000, 1000-parameter1 ) desc
LIMIT 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/988d4/6/1)

Comment: this always returns parameter2-1000 attribute and what I want is if parameter2-1000 > 1000-parameter1 than return parameter2-1000 else 1000-parameter1. BUT, these parameter2-1000 > 1000-parameter1(from my scenario) are from different rows and you need to look at them like that!!!

Comment: one more thing, my result needs to be single regardless of "LIMIT number"

Comment: :-) My whole concentration is on these parameters in a way that I'm comparing spread between my parameter and parameter2 in FIRST ROW and spread between my parameter and parameter1 in SECOND ROW.

Comment: it seems that you want the greatest from least ... look at the resultset, the first row should be your result row http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14298/23/0

Comment: this could be it. I'll check it a bit more over weekend because I need this to work properly and I'll answer you. till then you should update your answer! thank you man for you effort

Comment: after testing of your query with my scenario I consider this as answer, dude!:-) thanks for your effort. hope we'll meet again:-)